# Webhook Subscription to SharedWithMe

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using the Microsoft Graph API, I am able to subscribe to Webhooks callbacks on a drive and receive notifications when content is added, modified, or deleted from that drive.

What I have not been able to figure out is a way to subscribe to notifications on content shared to a user. In other words, adding, modifying, or deleting content in the "Shared With Me" folder.

I tried sending a subscription request for resource `/drives/{driveId}/sharedWithMe`, but it returns an error saying that the resource is not supported.

Is there any way to set up Webhooks for content shared with a user? I would like to receive a notification when content is shared to a user or when content shared to a user is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Old ticket but if anyone, like myself, come across this ticket here is what Microsoft says:

> Your app will not receive notifications for items that have been shared with the user who has signed in or remote items in the user's drive unless separate subscriptions are created on the original items.

So, depending on how your app works you can manage to get subscription and consent from original items (user who shared needs give your app permissions).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/using-webhooks?view=odsp-graph-online